# The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory

Tags: maven, maven-3

Iam getting error while installing maven build failure

I tried to install maven.
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

Comment: You are in a wrong directory. Make sure that you are in the same directory as the pom.xml